# UIDatePicker minimumdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I'm confused with one question. I don't understand where I made mistake

I needed make minimumdate for my UIDatePicker near 1810 year. So I try make it like

```
    datePicker.minimumDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970: - (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160)];
```

But I get wrong minimumdate:
[image]

So I went the other way and solved the problem

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.year = -160;
datePicker.minimumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0] options:0];
```

But I can'nt understand why in the first case I get wrong minimumdate

Comment: All days are not same. Daylight, leaps.....

Comment: I wonder if the problem goes away if you do an explicit "`-1 * 60 * 60 * ...`"?

Comment: try by  `60.0 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160` **make one of then float**

Comment: Anoop Vaidya yeah it's help solve problem =) Write youe answer for check like best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datePicker.minimumDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970: - (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160)];
```

160 Years are not `60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours * 365 days`.

You did not take consideration of various factors, one of the easiest to know is leap year.

Edit:

Use `60.0 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160` to  make one of then float, so the result will be `float` as you may exceed the int32(ios) range.

Comment: That might be true, but his result of the year 1946 is nowhere near 1810, so I don't *think* leap year miscalculation is the problem here.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: after reading Natan answer, I guess he is right, shouldnt he try to use double instead of int. try by 60.0 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160 **make one of then float**

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this has to do with the maximum value of an int. Making this multiplication results in 5.045.760.000, and as you did it a multiplication of whole numbers and not 60.0 * 60.0 maybe this is the reason it's failing.

Try to put directly the number I posted here, or just declare it as a float and pass in to the method, or make one of them float so the result will be a float: - 60.0 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 160